# Mathematical equation tool for R markdown

Tags: r, math, markdown

I would like to insert math heavy equation into r markdown file.
I need a tool that convert equation that convert into r markdown rules.
ex) $\sigma = \frac{1/\lambda}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: Why not just use [LaTeX](http://gosset.wharton.upenn.edu/teaching/471/EPFL-Sweave-powerdot.pdf)?

Comment: Or, [katex](http://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/03a5bbeac312d27e99f6)

Comment: Or Sweave and RStudio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your final output. If your output file is PDF, knit uses LaTeX engine (pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX -- but I am not sure) and then LaTeX syntax will render equation well. If your output is HTML you have to use mathML because LaTeX code will not be parsed nor rendered but displayed as is. In the latter case you have to convert LaTeX to mathML, there are a lot of tools online to do that.

If you do not know a little of LaTeX is very hard. An useful tool might be [this](http://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/) one. It allows you to see symbols and the correspondent code, after that you can copy the code or just render it as a picture to insert in RMarkdown.

An example of HTML output might be this, where equations are in LaTeX code and they will be rendered in the proper way because of the additional `$$` at the end and the beginning of the equation. I think they trigger the mathjax script (which is very slow).

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "SabaDem"
date: "20 giugno 2015"
output: html_document
---

This is an HTML file
$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{x^2}{x^3+x^5}
\end{equation}
$$
```

Let me know if this solution work for you because on old version of Rstudio it might doesn't work.

If you have to share these files users have to have an active internet connections because RMarkdown set by default to recover mathjax script on mathjacs.org servers.

Of course **(that's why I said at the beginning "it depends on...")** if your final output if PDF, the code here will trigger an error because those `$$` are not recognized by LaTeX (which render PDF).

Comment: I believe there is a misrepresentation regarding my question. First, I need a tool to build the math heavy equations... Second, I need a tool that convert that equation into R markdown somehow.. Do tool do you use?

Comment: I am sorry maybe there is a misunderstanding but I have no idea about what a **math heavy equation** is and honestly I don't think is possible to achieve what you are asking. Markdown itself has no trace of equations or math in its official documentation which you can find [here](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) that's why there are a lot of tools to convert and interpret other markup languages piece of code (like LaTeX) embedded in Markdown.